# Background img responsive design

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to use a hover on a background img like so:

```
.featuredimg{background: url('[imgPathHere]');
             width:370px;
             height:430px;}
.featuredimg:hover{background: url('[imgPathHere]')0px -430px;}
```

The issue is that I'm using twitter bootstrap so that the site is responsive. How do I continue to use background img hovers while allowing the image to scale. Right now the image stays the same width and height regardless of window size.

Comment: Do you mean stack them with `z-index` and display the parent none on hover?

Comment: @jtheman Really?  You can't?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 0):

Use the **:before / :after** instead or **background-size** property to zoom your background images.